# How to get the value of an input and use it for an http request Angular 4

Tags: angular, http, request

I'm new in Angular and I wanted to know if what I want to do is possible>\

First, I want to create a page with an input and when you put a link on this input, it get it and use it in order to make an http request.

Thank u for your help

Answer (score 0):

**Getting the value of the input**

Yes you absolutely can! Here is an example of a simple component that has an input with a handler on the (change) event.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ExampleService } from './example.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'example',
    template: `
      <input (change)="onChange($event)">
    `
})
export class ExampleComponent {
  constructor(
      private service: ExampleService
  ) { }

  onChange(e: Event) {
    let value = e.target['value'];
    this.service.get(value).subscribe(res => {
      console.log('res: ', res);
    })
  }
}
```

When the input value is changed it emits an event to the onChange() function in your component. The change event object stores the input in its 'target' property, and you can access the value of the input with: e.target['value'].

**Http Requests**

What you want to do is create a service that has a method to make http requests and then call it from your component.

You need to import the service add it to the components constructor before you can use it.

You can then pass in the value of the input as an argument to the service and use it however you want.

Here is an example of the service.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class ExampleService {

  constructor(private http: Http) { }

  get(link: string): Observable<any>{
    // assuming link = https://facebook.com/123456789?param=something
    let url = link.split('facebook.com/')[1].split('?')[0];

    return this.http.get(url)
        .map(res => res.json());
}
```

Note you can use regex to parse the facebook url too.

Hope that helps. Good luck with Angular! :)

Comment: Thank u very much, I have an other question, is it possible to take only a part of the link? For example this link : https://facebook.com/197875396963676, I only want this part "197875396963676" thank u.

Comment: Sure you'll need to process it. I'll add it to my answer.

Comment: @Mehdieuros K I added a line in the server get() method that extracts the facebook id from the link. You can use any type of string manipulation to parse it however you want before passing it to the http.get() method.

Answer (score 0):

There are various methods in which you can access the input.

**Two way binding**
**Event Binding**

```
<input type="text" (input)="onUpdate($event)">
```

and in the component.ts

```
 onUpdate(event: Event) {   
    console.log((<HTMLInputElement>event.target).value);
  }
```

**Local Reference and @ViewChild**

```
<input type="text" #inputName>
```

and in the component.ts

```
@ViewChild('inputName') serverContent: ElementRef;
```

**Local Reference send in methods**

```
<input type="text"  #inputName>
<button (click)="onSend(inputName)">Send</button>
```

and in the component.ts

```
onAddServer(nameInput: HTMLInputElement) {
    console.log(nameInput.value);        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's completely possible. See below code :

Make **component** like :

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { YourService } from './yourservicename.service'; //file path

@Component({
    selector: 'getdata',
    template: `
      <input [(ngModel)]="inputUrl" (blur)="getData()"> //fetch data on blur
    `
})
export class ExampleComponent {
inputUrl : string="":
  constructor(private service: YourService) { }

  getData() {
    // call service here
    this.service.getDataFromService(this.inputUrl ).subscribe(response=> {
      // handle response
    })
  }
}
```

In **Service** Code :

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class YourService{
  constructor(private http: Http) { }

  getDataFromService(url: string): Observable<any>{
    return this.http.get(url)
        .map(res => res.json());
}
```